# How can I read table of type "table of String"?

Tags: abap

How can I read internal table of type "table of String"?

I tried `read itab with key k = lv_value Transporting no fields.` but what should I use for `k`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the pseudo-component `table_line` [as described in the documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/fc/eb35f8358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm).